# Files lager than block size on HDFS doesn't detach

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs

My block size of HDFS is 256MB.I read one file of size 9.9GB of type txt and transformed it into orc type
using spark and the size of it is downsized to  1.29GB by calling `write` method:

```
dataframe.coalesce(16).write.mode("overwrite")
.partitionBy("myDate").
orc("hdfs://myhost:9090/user/hive/warehouse/ods/data.orc")
```

I imagine that when I look at my result on HDFS UI and browse the files,there should be 16 files under `data.orc` directory and each file's size is less than block size 256MB. However, there is only one directory `mydate=20210131`, and when I go into it,there is only one 1.29GB file,which is much greater than block size 256MB.

This situation confuses me，could anyone please tell me :

1. Why can a 1.29 GB file be put into single 256MB block? Do I have some misunderstanding here?
2. Why files are not devided into smaller files even I called coalesce(16) to try to devide them into 16 partiotions thus there are 16 files?
3. If my files are smaller than 256MB,say 200MB, will the remaining 56MB be reused by the system?

Answer (score 0):

1. I have made it clear to myself that a file larger than block size is saved in multiple blocks,but there is only one file on HDFS.
2. In local mode,there is only one executor,the driver.And I called `partiitonBy(mycol)` in my code ,there is only  so there is only single value in the column `mycol`,so there is only one file.
3. Yes,unused space will not be occupied.